# ros2 nav2 costmap not working

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I made my own robot, and I wanted to use nav2 to control it. I have copied the turtlebot3 files and changed them to work with my robot. Everything works, I can even give it commands via rviz. However, the costmap doesn't work. I have tried everything and yet can't seem to get it working. All I changed was the world that was used by gazebo, the robot itself and I changed the map to my map and made small changes to the yaml file

This is the yaml file that I use:

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "differential"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    debug_trajectory_details: True
    min_vel_x: 0.0
    min_vel_y: 0.0
    max_vel_x: 0.26
    max_vel_y: 0.0
    max_vel_theta: 1.0
    min_speed_xy: 0.0
    max_speed_xy: 0.26
    min_speed_theta: 0.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
    # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    acc_lim_x: 2.5
    acc_lim_y: 0.0
    acc_lim_theta: 3.2
    decel_lim_x: -2.5
    decel_lim_y: 0.0
    decel_lim_theta: -3.2
    vx_samples: 20
    vy_samples: 5
    vtheta_samples: 20
    sim_time: 1.7
    linear_granularity: 0.05
    xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    transform_tolerance: 0.2
    critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
    BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
    PathAlign.scale: 0.0
    GoalAlign.scale: 0.0
    PathDist.scale: 32.0
    GoalDist.scale: 24.0
    RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
      global_frame: odom
      plugin_names: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      plugin_types: ["nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer", "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"]
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      footprint_padding: 0.02
      footprint: "[[0.7, 0.375], [0.7, -0.375], [-0.2, -0.375], [-0.2, 0.375]]"
      inflation_layer:
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
      obstacle_layer:
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan1 scan2
        scan1:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
        scan2:
          topic: /scan2
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
      plugin_names: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      plugin_types: ["nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer", "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer", "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"]
      footprint_padding: 0.02
      footprint: "[[0.7, 0.375], [0.7, -0.375], [-0.2, -0.375], [-0.2, 0.375]]"
      obstacle_layer:
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan1 scan2
        scan1:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
        scan2:
          topic: /scan2
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: "../map/custom_map.yaml"

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    tolerance: 0.0
    use_astar: false

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
```

I can even see the updated footprint that I created, but the costmap itself refuses to load for some reason. Has anyone had this problem before, and knows how to solve it?

Edit to add:
as you can see in rviz, my robot is able to navigate. However the global and local costmaps both give a warning stating no map has been received.
[image: image description]

I would expect a costmap to be made and have the overlay as I have when I run the [turtlebot example](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_navigation2/#send-navigation-goal).

I am using navigation2 with the eloquent-devel branch, with the latest changes (the June 30th update)

2nd edit:
I checked my map server, which states the following:

```
[INFO] [map_server]: Loading yaml file: /home/user/eloquent_ws/install/nena_navigation2/share/nena_navigation2/params/custom_map.yaml
[INFO] [map_server]: Loading image_file: /home/user/eloquent_ws/install/nena_navigation2/share/nena_navigation2/params/custom_map.pgm
```

My controller server also says that it's creating the costmap and my planner server states this:

```
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 414 X 621 at 0.050000 m/pix
```

Which is the size of my map according to the custom_map.pgm

My planner_server does however also show me this message:

```
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap_rclcpp_node]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'lidar1' at time 10.968 for reason 'Unknown'
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap_rclcpp_node]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'lidar2' at time 10.969 for reason 'Unknown'
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap_rclcpp_node]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'lidar2' at time 19.076 for reason 'Unknown'
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap_rclcpp_node]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'lidar1' at time 19.076 for reason 'Unknown'
```

With about 250 lines in between, with only the time changing. But it does stop after that last message, even though I ran the navigation for longer, and from what I could find online it was just something that hadn't been fixed yet, it wasn't anything bad, so I don't really know

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360725/ros2-nav2-costmap-not-working/) by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1124 on 2020-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) on 2020-09-01**:
Which ROS distribution do you use? If it is old, it may be related to this PR:
https://github.com/ros2/rviz/pull/375

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2020-09-01**:
I'm using Eloquent, so I don't think it's related, but thank you for taking the time to answer regardless!

**Comment by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on 2020-09-02**:
I am actually not sure what exactly is not working in your case. Could you be a little more specific about that?

There has been a change in the plugin interface ([see here](interface https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/commit/f3b7be2397f585c53d4940b0fc516d8fe4738670#diff-654f280b3f7a18a77bdf3f828c8538f1)). Which version of navigation2 are you using? From what i can see, your yaml file still uses the old interface.

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2020-09-02**:
First, let me say thank you for taking the time to help me.
Second, I have updated the question to hopefully explain my issue better.
I am using the eloquent-devel branch of navigation2, with its latest changes.
I have used the turtlebot yaml file in the eloquent-devel branch to make my yaml file, so I'm not sure if I'm using the old interface to be honest (and your link doesn't work for me, for some reason)

**Comment by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on 2020-09-03**:
Looks like the new plugin interface does not effect the eloquent branch. Anyway, sorry for the broken link. For the sake of completeness: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/foxy-devel/doc/parameters/param_list.md#node-costmap_2d_ros

Are you sure, that the map file `./map/custom_map.yaml` exists and is published correctly (especially with matching QoS)? Are there any relevant Log messages from the map server/ controller server?

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2020-09-03**:
I updated my question again, I hope I answered your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I found out what the problem was. The turtlebot is included in the world file. My robot was spawned in using the gazebo_ros spawner. This means I had to use gazebo_ros_factory.so when starting Gazebo. It seems I didn't start that properly. It started well enough not to report any errors, and it spawned my robot correctly. However it did break my costmap somehow

ETA:
Just in case somebody has this problem. I start the `gzserver` using:

```
start_gazebo_server_cmd = ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['gzserver', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
    cwd=[this_share_dir], output='screen')
```

Not including the `'-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'` part seemed to break it. I have no idea how or why, but that seemed to be my issue.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2020-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [divyam.rastogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/50312/divyam.rastogi/) on 2021-03-04**:
I am facing the same issue. Were you able to fix it?